# What mechanisms generate the emergence of particular structures in networks

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, networks

I'm a new member and I have some questions about the distinct processes that explain the emergence of a particular structure in networks. I'm new in this domain and if I understand well, the actual theories are:

- If the degree distribution follows an exponential law, the mechanism of attachment is random.
- If the degree distribution follows an log-normal law, the mechanism of attachment is mixed (random and preferential).
- If the degree distribution follows a power law, the mechanism of attachment is by preferential.

If I'm wrong, can you give me some explanation and some references please?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with Newman's *Networks: an Introduction*. It's a very readable textbook on the mathematics of networks.